# How do I find all memory allocations in an llvm ir code file?

Tags: llvm, clang

I tried to compile this snippet of C++ code:

```
void FuncTest() {
    int* a = new int;
    int* b = new int[2];
}
```

Using:

```
clang test.cpp -S -emit-llvm -o - > test.llvm
```

And obtained this:

```
define void @_Z8FuncTestv() {
entry:
  %a = alloca i32*, align 4
  %b = alloca i32*, align 4
  %call = call noalias i8* @_Znwj(i32 4)
  %0 = bitcast i8* %call to i32*
  store i32* %0, i32** %a, align 4
  %call1 = call noalias i8* @_Znaj(i32 8)
  %1 = bitcast i8* %call1 to i32*
  store i32* %1, i32** %b, align 4
  ret void
}

declare noalias i8* @_Znwj(i32)
declare noalias i8* @_Znaj(i32)
```

What I am wondering now is: where do the `_Znwj` and `_Znaj` symbols come from? Are they just randomly assigned or is there a system to it? I would like to be able to tell that the lines:

```
%call = call noalias i8* @_Znwj(i32 4)
```

and

```
%call1 = call noalias i8* @_Znaj(i32 8)
```

perform memory allocations. But it does not look that promising.

Some llvm expert here who has an idea?

Comment: I could add that if there is a way to know this (where memory allocations are) from within a clang/llvm toolchain pass it would be fine as well, just please tell me how.

Answer (score 5):

You're seeing the C++ mangled name of the operator. Demangle the symbol using [abi::__cxa_demangle](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html), or build up a table of mangled symbols. The new/delete operators may be overloaded so the symbols are not constant. Demangling may be the safest option.

This is the function piped through c++filt, which in turn uses [abi::__cxa_demangle](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html):

```
define void @FuncTest()() {
entry:
  %a = alloca i32*, align 4
  %b = alloca i32*, align 4
  %call = call noalias i8* @operator new(unsigned int)(i32 4)
  %0 = bitcast i8* %call to i32*
  store i32* %0, i32** %a, align 4
  %call1 = call noalias i8* @operator new[](unsigned int)(i32 8)
  %1 = bitcast i8* %call1 to i32*
  store i32* %1, i32** %b, align 4
  ret void
}

declare noalias i8* @operator new(unsigned int)(i32)
declare noalias i8* @operator new[](unsigned int)(i32)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a function is allocating memory through isAllocationFn. It seems to work for me.

Source: http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/namespacellvm.html#a455d82c49557ac1d6c8da8e8d86a94b5

PD: I'm responding the question on the title, which is what brought me here.